# Static UITableView not fullscreen

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

For my registration form, I am currently using a UITableView which isn't fullscreen and I add cells programmatically through hardcoding the datasource methods. By the time the whole class got very complex and huge.
[Pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/9R2Fa1Uy)

The cells are custom and have a UILabel and a UITextfield. Now one of the cells should have a button instead of the textfield. This would make the whole thing more complex then it should be, in my opinion. So my thought was using the static feature of the tableview in the storyboard. But this requiers a UITableViewController, if I use one the TableView is always fullscreen. Is there a way to se the static feature without a fullscreen TableView??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a fixed number of cells, the static table view controller is a good option. Instead of implementing the datasource methods, as you mentioned, you can include each input field as an IB outlet.

If you want a static table view controller that is not full-width, embed the table view controller inside a container view.

For example, create a new view controller, add a container view object w/ the desired width in this new view controller, and then connect your static table view controller to the container view.

Note that the static table view controller becomes a childViewController of the enclosing view controller. You can facilitate access to the textFields from the enclosing view controller w/ a weak property to the textFields w/in the child view controller.

```
- (UITextField *)surnameTextField
{
  UITextField *textField;

  // reference childController that is initiated via containerView
  if ([[self.childViewControllers lastObject] isKindOfClass:[NameViewController class]])
  {
    NameViewController *nameVC = [self.childViewControllers lastObject];
    textField = nameVC.surnameTextField;
  }

  return textField;
}
```

Comment: This seems like the best solution for this. In the end it should kike this,[link](http://image-upload.de/image/M7ryGE/a57bdfa7ad.png), do you think using a view with the table as a background and some labels and textfields is the better solution??

Comment: Yes, I'd place that table view controller inside the container view, set the labels inside interface builder, and then ctrl-drag the textFields as IB Outlets into the static table view controller class. Eliminates quite a bit of code and easier to maintain since you can see everything in the storyboard. This was how I replicated the "Add Contact" scene in the address book.

Comment: Ok, I have one question left, is there a way to send a message from the tableviewcontroller to the viewcontroller?

Comment: Try sending the message to self.parentViewController

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use a UITableViewController. Just drag and drop a table view from the control palette onto a UIViewController in your storyboard. Size and position it how you want to and add any other controls to the UIViewController that you need.

In the property sheet for the UITableView set the content type to 'Static Cells' then define your cells how you want them.

[image]

Comment: If you do it like this, xcode gives you the error: Static table views are only valid when embedded in UITableViewController instances